# How to compare remote with local after local version of remote is messed up

Tags: git, github

So I had some changed files, some of which I staged then commit using Git Gui.

After I push the selected ones, Github can't detect the other changed file which I didn't commit yet. So now my remote and local is mismatched. I now added even more changes to my local. 
Now I've no idea how to match the the remote with the local. I tried git diff `<local>` `<remote>` but it shows nothing.

I cant really reset my head either, cause then it will discard all the changes right?

Comment: "After I push the selected ones": to what does the pronoun "one" refer here?  You can only push *commits*, not files, and you do so by telling the remote to set a name (usually a branch) to point to some *specific* commit, i.e., you push commit `a123456` (often by its name, e.g., `feature`) and get the remote to set its branch `feature` to point to `a123456`.  It's not clear from your question what you committed, nor what you pushed.

Comment: oh my bad. There were unstaged changes showing in git gui. So i selected some of those files and stage change them. Then commit and push. Then after i reopen git gui the unstaged change are all gone, and my local thinks remote is same as local. What's worse is that I have added new changes ever since. Does that clear it up?

Comment: Yes: doing a commit takes whatever is staged (along with every file that was in the previous commit) and makes a new commit from that.  I don't use the GUI, but presumably whatever files you selected were staged and hence in the new commit.  The push then pushed the commit, so the remote's commit is now the same as your local commit.  This is why `git diff <local> <remote>` shows nothing: these are the same.  When your new changes are ready, stage and commit them, and comparing the local and remote commits will now show differences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply fetch and do `git diff master..origin/master`.